# How to display the results of two queries side by side?

Tags: mysql

In mysql, I need to display the results of these two queries, side by side, not vertically (when using UNION).

First query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(cod = 'teste') as Cod1, id_user
FROM
  Log
WHERE month = 4 AND year = 2014 AND cod = 'test'
GROUP BY
  id_user
```

Second query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT info) as Cod2, id_user
FROM
  Log
WHERE month = 4 AND year = 2014 AND cod = 'test'
GROUP BY
  id_user
```

The result, should be something like:

```
Cod1          id_user          Cod2              id_user
 10              1              8                  1
 5               2              3                  2
```

Is that possible?

Comment: "Side by side" is an arbitrary graphical description. Can you pose the question in SQL terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need two columns for id_user because they are always going to be the same, right?

You can use subqueries to join your two queries together "side by side", like this:

```
SELECT 
  q1.id_user as id_user
  q1.Cod1 as Cod1, 
  q2.Cod2 as Cod2
FROM 
 (SELECT
    SUM(cod = 'teste') as Cod1, 
    id_user
  FROM Log
  WHERE month = 4 AND year = 2014 
    AND cod = 'test'
  GROUP BY id_user) as q1

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT info) as Cod2, 
     id_user
   FROM Log
   WHERE month = 4 AND year = 2014 
     AND cod = 'test'
   GROUP BY id_user) as q2
ON q1.id_user = q2.id_user
```

Or in this example, you can do it without using subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT
  id_user,
  SUM(cod = 'teste') as Cod1, 
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT info) as Cod2
FROM Log
  WHERE month = 4 AND year = 2014 
    AND cod = 'test'
  GROUP BY id_user
```

Code not tested, so there might be a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with returning multiple columns, like normal?

```
SELECT
  SUM(cod = 'teste') as Cod1,
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT info) as Cod2,
  id_user
FROM
  Log
WHERE month = 4 AND year = 2014 AND cod = 'test'
GROUP BY
  id_user
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, you can use the following -

```
with 
  query1 as ( select .... ),   -- your existing query1
  query2 as ( select .... )   -- your existing query2
select *
from query1, query2
where query1.product = query2.product;
```

Ref - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9526403800346400896